# Running an old Angular project

Tags: angular

I have an old `Angular` project that specifies the following requirements:

- `npm`@6.14.12
- `yarn`@1.22.10
- `nodejs`@14.16.0 (LTS)
- `typescript`@4.2.4
- `angular/cli`@11.2.14
- `bootstrap`@5.0.1

I would like to open it in the newest `Visual Studio Code` and run it with the latest versions available for cli and node and typescript, etc...

Just so I don't mess anything up, what is the first thing I should do when opening an old Angular project on a machine that has the very latest software? Should I just run it with `ng serve`? Should I run `npm install` first?

And then, would the software version differences affect other project partners who use `git` to contribute?

Comment: Start here: https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just so I don't mess anything up, what is the first thing I should do when opening an old Angular project on a machine that has the very latest software? Should I just run it with ng serve? Should I run npm install first?

in order to run the project, you need to run `npm install` first to fetch the dependencies, then run it with `npm start` or whatever the run script in `package.json` is defined.

If you want to update the angular dependencies to the latest version, you need to run:

```sh
npx ng update  # this will run update for angular specific stuff
```

If you want to update other packages, you can change the version numbers in `package.json` manually, then run `npm install` to fetch them.

> And then, would the software version differences affect other project partners who use git to contribute?

Yes, if you push your changes, they must install the same versions you pushed to work with your state of the project with `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

open your project and in the terminal write "npm i" after it's done intalling you can create a localhost with "ng serve".

Note: If needed:
(if you want to open in visual studio write "code ." this command will open visual studio then you can do "ng serve")